# Google maps Places API V3 auto-complete search box diff between search term / place selected

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm using the Google maps Places API V3 auto-complete (google.maps.places.SearchBox) and I added following listener to it :

```
searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
     //not available at start, will be set later.
    //updateGoogleAutoCompleteSearchBoundFromMap();
    //listener if the user selected a poi or text
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
            ...
```

So I'm wondering now the search box gives me concrete places and then search term auto-complete. No matter what I choose in the list, I get an array with places object with a places id. Can I differentiate somehow if a user selected a search term or a concrete places id?

Because I would like to act different then.
I couldn't find anything in the documentation so I'm afraid I'm not able to differentiate....

Because if the user picks a concrete place, I want to show that place and only that place. If not, I would like to use the search term for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still dont really know why the autocomplete acts differenet on some of my machines. But i figured out it was actually pretty simple since they array size is always 1 when you pick a place and >1 if you pick a text. So thanks anyways